# how to generate array B in the state-space model in matlab

Tags: matlab, state-space

I would like to plot in matlab the transfer function which comes from the state-space model:

```
G * x + C * x’= B * ip(t)

up(t) = LT  * x.
```

In above formula G,C have been read from a file and their size is 1882*1882, `ip(t) = [i1 i2 i3 i3 i5]'` (input), `up(t) = [u1 u2 u3 u4 u5]'` (output) due to a 5-port system and `x = [V1 V2 .... V1161 I1 I2 .. I721]` (Number of nodes: 1161,number of inductive branches: 721).

According to theory B must be an orthogonal(in our case 1882*5) source connectivity matrix mapping `uin(t)` to the `MNA` vector `x`. My problem is that i don't know how to generate the matrix `B` with code in matlab. How could i know which positions of the matrix have 1 and how to implement this with code?

Thank you very much in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: Does anyone know how could I implement the above suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this constitutes as a transfer function. What is G, C, x an ip? Which modeling type is this ?

Comment: I am refering to this modeling type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation. The transfer function is represented by G(s) as you can see in the middle of the above link page.

Comment: I know what those are. What is your first equation then ? You are in time domain to start with. Transfer functions are in s domain and so on... This is not a standard model you are using

Comment: The first equation can be easily transformed to the state space model as:     A= -G(^-1)  * C, B= G(^-1) * B. Therefore we have x'=A*x + B * ip(t)  and y L(^T)*x, where ip(t) the input of the system and L=B.

Comment: How can i express matrix B in matlab?

Comment: Ah so the prime is the derivative ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ugly notation

Comment: I think your problem is not about state space but reverse engineering the mapping regarding the connectivity matrix. If you  recompose your question then probably you will attract more people.